# What is the correct way to pass filepath in ctypes

Tags: python, python-2.7, ctypes, dllexport

I have dll driver with `function(char* filename,int run)`. I am calling from Python 2.7 with ctypes like

```
import ctypes as ct
mydll = ct.cdll.LoadLibrary(dll_file_path)
function = mydll.function
function.argtypes=(ct.POINTER(ct.c_char_p),ct.c_int)
function.restype=ct.c_int


filename=b'C:\\Users\\data.dat'

function(ct.c_char_p(filename),100)
```

I was reading online and some said it is better to use `ct.create_string_buffer`. I don't know how to use it. I got error with `ct.POINTER(ct.c_char_p)`. My question is which is the correct way to pass filepath/name in ctypes and if `ct.creat_string_buffer` is the right way, how do I have to change `function.argtypes`?

Comment: A C string is a null-terminated `char` array,  which is typically passed as a char pointer, i.e. `char *`. In ctypes this is best represented by `c_char_p`, though sometimes you may want `POINTER(c_char)`.  But `POINTER(c_char_p)` is a C `char **`, which you certainly don't want in this case.